# How to retrieve Location Objects from a database?

Tags: android, database, gps, location

I want to store Location objects into my database, and then be able to load them. How can I build a Location object from its attributes?

- Should I create a blank Location and then set the attributes? (If yes, how?)
- Should I use my database as a LocationProvider? (If yes, how?)

Thanks!

**EDIT: The only working solution I found so far is to retrieve the current Location, and override all the attributes... There has to be a better way!**

my code:

```
public Location selectLocationById(int id){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + LOCATIONS_TABLE + " WHERE id = " + id + ";";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Location l = null;
    if(c.getCount() == 1) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.getColumnCount() == 8){
            l = new Location(MyProject.getCurrentLoc());
            l.setAccuracy(c.getFloat(1));
            l.setAltitude(c.getDouble(2));
            l.setBearing(c.getFloat(3));
            l.setLatitude(c.getDouble(4));
            l.setLongitude(c.getDouble(5));
            l.setSpeed(c.getFloat(6));
            l.setTime(c.getLong(7));
        }
    }

    if(c != null && !c.isClosed()) {
        c.close();
    }

    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes sense. I believe you could use

```
l = new Location(null);
```

So that you don't have to get your current location. This should still create a new Location, but with a provider string of null, using the other Location constructor:

```
Location(String provider)
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: Thanks, it works.
l = new Location((String)null);

I was using the wrong constructor, which throws Null Pointer Exception:
l = new Location((Location)null);

Comment: Nice, glad you used the (String) that I missed as well, haha.